# Android Fragment activity shown fullscreen

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments, openstreetmap, android-fullscreen

I have a question regarding a fragment layout of an OSM Map. I'd like to display the fragment within the activity in full screen modus.
However, the map is only shown on two thirds of the screen.

How can this be achieved?
Can this be done only be editing the .xml file or do I need to make any changes at the manifest or main activity as well?

Here the .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8.01" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the MapFragment.java file:

```
    package com.example.uadclient;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Patter
import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.ExtendedOverlayItem;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.ItemizedOverlayWithBubble;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Polyline;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.Road;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.RoadManager;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing.RoadNode;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedIconOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverlay;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.uadclient.R;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {


      private MapController mMapController;
      private MapView mMapView;
      private ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> myLocationOverlay;
      protected ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadNodes;
      protected PathOverlay roadOverlay;

      FileInputStream fis = null;
      private ResourceProxy mResourceProxy; 
      private LocationManager mLocMgr;
      String s = ""; 
      String s1 = "";
      String s2 = "";


      String lon = "";
      String lat = "";
      int mIncr = 10000;
      int counter; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(inflater.getContext().getApplicationContext());
        mMapView = new MapView(inflater.getContext(), 256, mResourceProxy);

            //read GPS data from file
            readfromFile(); 
            readfromFile2();

            readfromFile();
            String str1;
            str1 = s1.toString();

            readfromFile2();
            String str2;
            str2 = s2.toString();

            try {
                countLines();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


            lon = str1;
            lat = str2;

            while (counter > 0){ //Anzahl Zeilen -> Anzahl der Punkte

            double var_lon = Double.parseDouble(lon);
            double var_lat = Double.parseDouble(lat);   


            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meetfragment, null);
            mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
            mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
            mMapController = mMapView.getController();
            mMapController.setZoom(13);

                GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(var_lat, var_lon);
                GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(52.120310618246236, 9.905589604799236); // centre map 
                GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint(52.11712212336459, 9.899281049195961);

                mMapController.setCenter(point1);
                //mMapController.setCenter(point3);
                ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(3);
                // Put overlay icon on the centre
                items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", point1));
               /* items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", point2));
                items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "SampleDescription", point3));*/


                ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(3);
                waypoints.add(point1);
                waypoints.add(point2);
                waypoints.add(point3);


         //       new UpdateRoadTask().execute(waypoints);

                if (savedInstanceState == null){
                    //Test road service at first launch:
                    getRoadAsync(point1, point2);
                } else {
                    Road mRoad = null;
                    updateUIWithRoad(mRoad);
                }

               this.myLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                        new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index,
                                    final OverlayItem item) {

                                return true; 
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index,
                                    final OverlayItem item) {

                                return false;
                            }
                        }, mResourceProxy);     



                this.mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.myLocationOverlay); 
                counter--; 
                return v;
               }



            return container;}

    public void getRoadAsync(GeoPoint start, GeoPoint destination){
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(2);
        waypoints.add(start);
        //intermediate waypoints can be added here:
        //waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(48.226, -1.9456)); 
        waypoints.add(destination);
        new UpdateRoadTask().execute(waypoints);
    }

    void updateUIWithRoad(Road road){
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mMapView.getOverlays();
        if (roadOverlay != null){
            mapOverlays.remove(roadOverlay);
        }
        if (road.mStatus == Road.STATUS_DEFAULT)
            Toast.makeText(mMapView.getContext(), "We have a problem to get the route", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, mMapView.getContext());
        Overlay removedOverlay = mapOverlays.set(1, roadOverlay);
            //we set the road overlay at the "bottom", just above the MapEventsOverlay,
            //to avoid covering the other overlays. 
        mapOverlays.add(removedOverlay);
        putRoadNodes(road);
        mMapView.invalidate();

    }

      private void putRoadNodes(Road road){
        roadNodes.removeAllItems();
        Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_node);
        int n = road.mNodes.size();
        TypedArray iconIds = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.direction_icons);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            RoadNode node = road.mNodes.get(i);
            String instructions = (node.mInstructions==null ? "" : node.mInstructions);
            ExtendedOverlayItem nodeMarker = new ExtendedOverlayItem(
                    "Step " + (i+1), instructions, 
                    node.mLocation, this);
            nodeMarker.setSubDescription(road.getLengthDurationText(node.mLength, node.mDuration));
            nodeMarker.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.CENTER);
            nodeMarker.setMarker(marker);
            int iconId = iconIds.getResourceId(node.mManeuverType, R.drawable.ic_empty);
            if (iconId != R.drawable.ic_empty){
                Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(iconId);
                nodeMarker.setImage(icon);
            }
            roadNodes.addItem(nodeMarker);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async task to get the road in a separate thread.
     */
      private class UpdateRoadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Road> {
            protected Road doInBackground(Object... params) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = (ArrayList<GeoPoint>)params[0];
                //RoadManager roadManager = new GoogleRoadManager();
                RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();
                /*
                RoadManager roadManager = new MapQuestRoadManager();
                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                roadManager.addRequestOption("locale="+locale.getLanguage()+"_"+locale.getCountry());
                */
                return roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
        }

         private void putRoadNodes(Road road){
             ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> roadNodes = null;
                roadNodes.removeAllItems();
                Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_node);
                int n = road.mNodes.size();
                TypedArray iconIds = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.direction_icons);
                for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    RoadNode node = road.mNodes.get(i);
                    String instructions = (node.mInstructions==null ? "" : node.mInstructions);
                    ExtendedOverlayItem nodeMarker = new ExtendedOverlayItem(
                            "Step " + (i+1), instructions, 
                            node.mLocation, this);
                    nodeMarker.setSubDescription(road.getLengthDurationText(node.mLength, node.mDuration));
                    nodeMarker.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.CENTER);
                    nodeMarker.setMarker(marker);
                    int iconId = iconIds.getResourceId(node.mManeuverType, R.drawable.ic_empty);
                    if (iconId != R.drawable.ic_empty){
                        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(iconId);
                        nodeMarker.setImage(icon);
                    }
                    roadNodes.addItem(nodeMarker);
                }
         }

    }





    public void onFinish(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.getActivity().finish();

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }



    public int countLines() throws IOException {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/GPSdata.txt");
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int readChars = 0;
            boolean empty = true;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                empty = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n') {
                        ++counter;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (counter == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : counter;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }


    public String readfromFile() {

        // Read from file
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        // Pattern being checked for lattidude
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1}.[0-9]+");

        Matcher m;

        // Der Pfad zur Textdatei
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/GPSdata.txt");
        try {
            // Der BufferedReader erwartet einen FileReader.
            // Diesen kann man im Konstruktoraufruf erzeugen.
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            String str = null;
            // null wird bei EOF oder Fehler zurueckgegeben
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Zeile auf der Konsole ausgeben
                // Pattern currently being checked for
                m = p1.matcher(line);
                if (m.find()) {
                    str = m.group();
                    // arrayList1.add(str);

                }

                System.out.println(line);
                s1 = str;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != bufferedReader) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return s1;

    }


    public String readfromFile2() {

        // Read from file
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        // Pattern being checked for longitude
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+.[0-9]+");

        Matcher m;

        // Der Pfad zur Textdatei
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/GPSdata.txt");
        try {
            // Der BufferedReader erwartet einen FileReader.
            // Diesen kann man im Konstruktoraufruf erzeugen.
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            String str1 = null;
            // null wird bei EOF oder Fehler zurueckgegeben
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Zeile auf der Konsole ausgeben
                // Pattern currently being checked for
                m = p.matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    str1 = m.group();
                    //arrayList2.add(str1);

                }

                System.out.println(line);
                s2 = str1;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != bufferedReader) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return s2;
    }



/*public void readLine(){
     try {
            BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GPSdata.txt"));
            String zeile = null;
            while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Gelesene Zeile:" + zeile);
            }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }



}*/




}
```

and here is the mainfest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.uadclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <permission
          android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.bosch.uadclient.MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service android:name="com.bosch.uadclient.LocationProviderService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Best Wishes

Comment: How is this connect with openstreetmap?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I replaced now the main activity file with the MapFragment.java File.

Comment: The preview within eclipse shows a fullscreen view whereas the preview at the phone shrinks the map together.